# git alias with argument for add

Tags: git, alias

I have a directory which contains a git repo and some other directories, most of which are long names.

```
MainDirectoryContainingRepo
    AnotherDirectoryWithLongName
        SomeFileName.xyz
        AnotherFileName.xyz
        SubDirectory
            ExampleFile.xyz
```

I would like to have an alias like

```
'ad = git add $1'
```

and invoke it with

```
git ad ExampleFile.xyz
```

rather than

```
git add AnotherDirectoryWithLongName/SubDirectory/ExampleFile.xyz
```

Any help with how I might do this?

Comment: What happens if you have two `ExampleFile.xyz`s?

Comment: I knew this would come up. I won't, but it would be a problem if I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of defining that alias, you could use a glob pattern:

```
git add **/ExampleFile.xyz
```

That would add any `ExampleFile.xyz` in any subfolder, recursively.